# How do I make an algorithm for a certain new number system I am developing?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

I am making a code, the context isn't important for this question, but in order to let the code work I need an algorithm of several entities. (For this example I used ASCII characters, to keep it simple.)

It needs to be like this code underneath.

```
[ a , b , c , d , e , ab , ac , ad , ae , bc , bd , be , cd , ce , de , abc , abd , abe , acd , ace , ade , abcd , abce , abcde ]
```

I would rather have some hints to help me get started, since this is the first algorithm I am developing, then having it all warmed up and served right in front of me. This way I can still try and develop it through my programmer's signature.

By the way, I am writing it in Python3.6 but I can read and convert any popular programming language.

Comment: Hint: take a look at `itertools` library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)

Comment: @Sqoshu I will do that

Comment: @Sqoshu I found it, combinations(). thanks!

Comment: No problem, enjoy coding ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a hint from @Sqoshu to use the `itertools` library so that should be enough to develop my code with if I am going to use `itertools.combinations()`.